# Starting a .NET process within an AppDomain

Tags: c#, process, appdomain

The title of my question might already give away the fact that I'm not sure about what I want, as it might not make sense.

For a project I want to be able to run executables within my application, while redirecting their standard in and out so that my application can communicate with them through those streams.

At the same time, I do not want to allow these executables to perform certain actions like use the network, or read/write outside of their own working directory (basically I only want to allow them to write and read from the standard in and out).

I read on different places on the internet that these permissions can be set with PermissionStates when creating an AppDomain in which you can then execute the executables. However, I did not find a way to then communicate with the executables through their standard in and out, which is essential. I can however do this when starting a new Process (`Process.Start()`), though then I cannot set boundaries as to what the executable is allowed to do.

My intuition tells me I should somehow execute the Process inside the AppDomain, so that the process kind of 'runs' in the domain, though I cannot see a way to directly do that.

A colleague of mine accomplished this by creating a proxy-application, which basically is another executable in which the AppDomain is created, in which the actual executable is executed. The proxy-application is then started by a Process in the main application. I think this is a cool idea, though I feel like I shouldn't need this step.

*I could add some code containing what I've done so far creating a process and appdomain, though the question is pretty long already. I'll add it if you want me to.*

Comment: This is extremely complex, sadly - there's a reason these approaches to security fail again and again, they're a huge effort and nobody gets them right. However, what you can do is run the process as a limited user - while it doesn't give you the granularity that CAS gives you, it's also a lot easier, and keeps the process isolation. In-process extensions can kill your application very easily :)

Comment: There is no way to run a process in an `AppDomain`, because they are completely separate concepts. `AppDomain`s run in processes, not vice versa. And of course, they only work for .NET applications in the first place :)

Comment: @Luaan then what happens when i call `AppDomain.Create(...).ExecuteAssembly(pathToMyStuff)` ? It feels to me like that starts a new process, but according to your statement this is not the case...

Comment: It executes the entry point method in the given assembly, within the given `AppDomain` (if I simplify, it does the equivalent of `GetType("Program").GetMethod("Main").Invoke();`). No new processes is spawned. `AppDomain` is really a mechanism for software isolated processes, but it's quite tricky to use, and the isolation is too limited for real sandboxing.

Comment: @Luaan I see, the proxy-application does actually sound more viable to me in that case. How would the main application in which a process with the proxy-app is created still manage to speak to the executable though, how does the redirected in and output of the proxy app know it should communicate with the loaded executable, or is it in fact the same?

Comment: Simple - the standard input and output of the "sandboxed" process is the same as the proxy application. Again, this is a process-level thing, not an `AppDomain`-level thing. .NET doesn't manage stdio, the C runtime/CSRSS/Windows does.

Comment: Yes, I see the (obvious) difference between a process and an appdomain more clearly now. It's confusing because they both sortof 'start' things, though an AppDomain simply loads it as part of the process it lives inside of. Thanks a lot for making these things more clear to me.

Comment: .NET MSDN documentation is actually pretty good - and on `ExecuteAssembly`, it actually explicitly states "This method does not create a new process or application domain, and it does not execute the entry point method on a new thread." I wonder how much effort we would save ourselves if we went back to the "check the documentation first" model, instead of expecting our assumptions to be correct, just because the name of the method is "Execute" :D For me, the original assumption stems from "It's on an `AppDomain`, so it *obviously* can't start a process." - and that *could* possibly be wrong.

Comment: You're right of course, and I hope you realise that typing a question like this does come after a while of reading documentations. However, documentation might not always be as clear, especially as it is written for readers that already have knowledge on the subject, something I have not. Being able to ask questions helps one bend his thoughts around a subject, which is why I now understand things better and might even know enough to fully make use of the documentation.

Comment: Sure, no offense intended - I rely on assumptions just as much as the next guy. Even though I read tons of documentation every month, I wouldn't be surprised if 90% (if not more) of the code I write relied entirely on my unconfirmed assumptions :)

Comment: I see what you're saying, and you're right. Check out this link, it illustrates what you're saying and it's generally just fun: http://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2015/07/03/upshot/a-quick-puzzle-to-test-your-problem-solving.html?_r=0

Comment: Heh, yeah. Fortunately, I was trained for biases like this, so it was quite trivial, but oh boy, our brains are *horrible* at science. It's a wonder we can make any rational progress at all - seeing truth through such flawed lens :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "proxy" application sounds like a very reasonable approach (given that you only ever want to run .NET assemblies).

You get the isolation of different processes which allows you to communicate via stdin/stdout and gives the additional robustness that the untrusted executable cannot crash your main application (which it could if it was running in an AppDomain inside your main application's process.

The proxy application would then setup a restricted AppDomain and execute the sandboxed code, similar to the approach described here:

> [How to: Run Partially Trusted Code in a Sandbox](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763046(v=vs.110).aspx)

In addition, you can make use of operation system level mechansims to reduce the attack surface of a process. This can be achieved e.g. by starting the proxy process with lowest integrity which removes write access to most resources (e.g. allow writing files only in AppData\LocalLow). See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40730318/40347) for an example.

Of course, you need to consider whether this level of sandboxing is sufficient for you. Sandboxing, in general, is hard, and the level of isolation always will be to a certain degree only.

Comment: I guess I don't really understand what the AppDomain does when it calles ExecuteAssembly(), to me it sounds like it starts yet another process, though apparently if I communicate to the proxy-application, Im actually speaking to the executable I want to talk to as it's loaded within the proxy-app through the created appdomain.

Comment: @Glubus: `ExecuteAssembly` will not start a new process but execute in the AppDomain in the same process. Therefore the communication works if you communicate with the "proxy"-application.

Comment: So you're saying that a Console.WriteLine() in the proxy-app is writing to the same stream when calling it in  the executed assembly when running it in the AppDomain? Seems halfway obvious to me now after reading your and Luaans comments.

Comment: @Glubus: I haven't tried this myself, but I would expect that to be the case because accessing stdin/stdout happens at process (and not AppDomain) level and the executed assembly runs within that particular process.

Comment: I see now how you would expect it, and it starts making sense to me. The proxy-application is not in fact an extra layer of execution in that sense as the program we aim to run is actually loaded as part of the proxy-app. I don't feel like I need to remove that layer anymore. Thanks a bunch!